# Distributing a python application

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a simple python application where my directory structure is as follows:

- project/

  - main.py
  - config.py
  - plugins/

    - plugin1
    - plugin2
    - ...

Config.py only loads configuration files, it does not contain any configuration info in itself.

I now want to distribute this program, and I thought I'd use setuptools to do it. The file users are expected to use is main.py, so that one clearly goes into /usr/bin and the rest of the files go into /usr/share/project.

But there's one problem: I would somehow need to tell main.py to look for config.py in the share directory. But I can't really be sure where exactly the share directory is since that's up to setuptools, right?

What's the best practice when distributing Python-based applications?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*setuptools* install your package in a location which is reachable from python i.e. you can import it:

```
import project
```

the problem raise when you do relative imports instead of absolute imports. if your `main.py` imports `config.py` it works because they live in the same directory. when you move your `main.py` to another location like `/usr/bin` or another location present in **PATH** environment variable, python try to import `config.py` from `sys.path` and not from your package dir. the solution is to use absolute import:

```
from project import config
```

now `main.py` is "movable".

another solution, which i prefer, is using automatic script creation offered by *setuptools*.

instead of having your code in a

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # here all your beautiful code
```

statement, put your code in a function (main could be a good name):

```
def main():
    # put your code here

if __name__ == "__main__":    # not needed, just in case...
    main()
```

now modify your `setup.py`:

```
setup(
    # ...
    entry_points = {
        "console_scripts": [
            # modify script_name with the name you want use from shell
            # $ script_name [params]
            "script_name = project.main:main",
        ],
    }
)
```

that's all. after an install *setuptools* will create a wrapper script which is callable from shell and that calls your main function. now `main.py` can live in your project directory and you don't need anymore to move it in a `bin/` directory. note that *setuptools* automatically puts this script in the `bin/` directory relative to the installation prefix.

es.

```
python setup.py install --prefix ~/.local
```

install your project package in

```
~/.local/lib/python<version>/site-packages/<package_name>
```

and your script in

```
~/.local/bin/<script_name>
```

so be sure that `~/.local/bin` is present in your **PATH** env.

more info at: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#automatic-script-creation

Comment: I guess I'm stupid, but I don't see how this is relevant? Could you elaborate?

Comment: i think i misunderstood your question. do you need to import `/usr/share/config.py`? this is not a good way to let the user customize the behavior of your application. a better solution is a per user configuration file like `$HOME/.projectrc` ad maybe a global configuration in `/etc/`. if this is your problem i'll correct my answer.

Comment: Yes, the issue is importing config.py. And in the question I specifically say that it does not contain any configuration information, it only contains the implementation to load the actual config files. It is a part of the program, not a configuration file or a plugin.

To be honest, I don't fully understand the entry_points thing. It might very well be what I'm looking for, but I find the documentation a bit confusing.

Comment: ok, maybe i got a better understanding of your question. setuptools install your package in a dir which is present in your PYTHONPATH or one that support ".pth" files. now you can, and i think you should, use `from mypackage import config`. even if "main.py" and "config.py" are in the same directory i think that this a good practice. (are you using `import config` in your "main.py"?). with "console_script" entry point you leave the main.py script in your package and automatically setuptools create a wrapper script that call the function you choose.

Comment: OK, now I think I get what you mean. Thanks! If you add that info to the original answer I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: Typo in this answer, using dictionary syntax with `:` inside a list.